# How to save a webpage as MHT archive files in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I've been searching for a Google Chrome way of -How to save a webpages as MHT archive files in Google Chrome?
but still no luck !!
As a Chromium project, it should have been easy to figure out, but why it's still not available in Google Chrome v43.0.2357.130 m ?

Comment: I can't find the solution in Google Chrome...plz help someone....

Answer (score 10):

1. Start the Chrome/Chromium browser
2. Navigate to "chrome://flags"
3. Find the entry "Save Page as MHTML"
4. Click "enable"
5. Restart your browser
6. That's it, now the web pages will be saved by default as MHTML

In Google Chrome Version 43.0.2357.130 m

Comment: The flag is gone from Chrome. However adding a `--save-page-as-mhtml` command line argument still works!